# Remove the non-decimal parts of a String using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove the non-decimal parts of a String which could include money (positive or negative values).

```
String value = "-$54.34"
value = value.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "")
```

Gives me `54.34`

It works when it's a non-negative, but in this case I want the negative sign to remain. All the other questions/answers seem to skip on the negative sign aspect.

I also don't want commas to show up in it...

$4,230.33 should strip out the commas.

Comment: `System.err.println(value.replaceAll("[^-,.\\d]", ""));` !?

Comment: `-,.` and all digits "remain" ..

Comment: maybe it is dup'ed, but not by [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555059/javascript-regular-expressions-replace-non-numeric-characters) tag:javascript..meanwhile i found: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/java-regex-match-any-currency-symbol/ ! which eneables us (for the specific "information loss") to `value.replaceAll("[\\p{Sc}]", "")` (replaces all "currency characters" with "empty string")

Comment: Sometimes there may be a plus sign.

Comment: Yeah it still keeps commas I think... Which is not good

Comment: What is your use case?  Do you want to parse this to a double?

Comment: Are you required to use a regular expression for this?  `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(value).intValue()` would accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.  Removes those characters that should not be part of a regular decimal number.

```
String[] testData = {
        "+$54.34","-$54.34","+54.34","-54.34","$54.34", "54.34",
        "+$1,054.34","-$1,054.34","+1,054.34","-1,054.34","$1,054.34", "1,054.34"
        
};
for (String value : testData) {
    String result = value.replaceAll("[^\\d.+-]+", "");
    System.out.printf("%10s -> %6s%n", value, result);
}
```

prints

```
   +$54.34 ->  54.34
   -$54.34 -> -54.34
    +54.34 ->  54.34
    -54.34 -> -54.34
    $54.34 ->  54.34
     54.34 ->  54.34
+$1,054.34 ->  1054.34
-$1,054.34 -> -1054.34
 +1,054.34 ->  1054.34
 -1,054.34 -> -1054.34
 $1,054.34 -> 1054.34
  1,054.34 -> 1054.34
```

I also suggest you check out [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which allows you to parse a `currencyInstance` to a double or to apply your own format.
If you want to convert to a double, first remove any plus or currency sign and parse.

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
df.applyPattern("#,##0.##");
for (String value : testData) {
    try {
       double result = df.parse(value.replaceAll("[+$]","")).doubleValue();
       System.out.printf("%10s -> %6s%n", value, result);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
       pe.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

prints the same as above.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the string only contains what refers to the money, but can the string get longer and contains " - " signs that are not the negative signs?

If your string always follow the same pattern as the one you just posted, you can change your regex to ignore " - " signs

```
String value = "-$54.34";
value = value.replaceAll("[^-\\d.]+", "");
System.out.println(value); // prints -54.34
```